# Is it necessary to define schema in order to insert data when using ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert data in `MySQL` database from `Node JS` by using `ORM`.

I looked into [Sequelize API](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) and [Caminte API](https://github.com/biggora/caminte), what i am seeing is that they are first creating table, and then inserting data in database.

But i have already created the database and all tables in it, i just want to insert data without creating tables or DB.

Why i am choosing `ORM` is to avoid following `raw insert queries`

> var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('Company
>   Inc', 'Highway 37')";

Following is the sample example defined in `Caminte API` docuemntation, similar type of documentation is also given by `Sequelize`.

What i am looking is to find a way to insert data in `DB` without creating any table from `ORM`

```
var User = schema.define('User', {
    name:       { type: schema.String,  limit: 255 },
    bio:        { type: schema.Text },
    email:      { type: schema.String,  limit: 155, unique: true },
    approved:   { type: schema.Boolean, default: false, index: true }
    joinedAt:   { type: schema.Date,    default: Date.now },
    age:        { type: schema.Number },
    gender:     { type: schema.String,  limit: 10 }
});
```

**//Saving Data**

```
user.isValid(function (valid) {
    if (!valid) {
        return console.log(user.errors);
    }
    user.save(function(err){
        if (!err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('User created');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For Sequelize, as long as you do not [synchronize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#database-synchronization), the DB schema won't be touch by Sequelize. No table created (or worse: dropped) etc... You can just plug and play with the already existing DB.